# rosbridge how to subscribe from multi rostopic

Tags: ros, subscribe, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that use such function I can use msg subscribe from the topic called /sensorPacket:

connection.callService('/rosjs/subscribe','["/sensorPacket",0]',function(rsp) {
alert('subscribed to /sensorPacket');
});

But I want information from 2 topics, for example /a and /b .
How can I realize? can I just use in such way:

connection.callService('/rosjs/subscribe','["/a,/b",0]',function(rsp) {
alert('subscribed to /sensorPacket');
});

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39697/rosbridge-how-to-subscribe-from-multi-rostopic/) by [koprenee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2889/koprenee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can reuse callbacks for multiple subscription requests and as the handler for incoming messages.

```
subscription_ok_callback = function(rsp) {
    alert("subscribed to /sensorPacket");
}

connection.callService("/rosjs/subscribe", '["/a", 0]', subscription_ok_callback);
connection.callService("/rosjs/subscribe", '["/b", 0]', subscription_ok_callback);

message_received_callback = function(msg) {
    alert("received a message: " + msg);
}

connection.addHandler("/a", message_received_callback);
connection.addHandler("/b", message_received_callback);
```

---

Originally posted by [Jon Mace](https://answers.ros.org/users/1507/jon-mace/) with karma: 431 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, my first answer was incorrect, and I have edited it for correctness.

---

Originally posted by [Jon Mace](https://answers.ros.org/users/1507/jon-mace/) with karma: 431 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1